# How to implement JXLS in Java file?

Tags: java, report, jxls

I want to convert my report into `Excel` sheet, But I don't know How to implement `JXLS` in `java` file.
Please suggest me the steps for implementation.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I am trying to display reports using JXLS api @agad

Comment: and? Where is a problem?

Comment: When I generate the excel file, then data is display like following                 Name  :  ${employee.name}   Payment : ${employee.payment}                    Bonus:  ${employee.bonus}.    I am confused about how to display the real data?   @agad

Comment: show us what you have tried first and then explain what problem you are facing...

Comment: I am simple following this link.. http://www.programering.com/a/MTN3UTMwATE.html but I am not getting where to put template code like Name : ${employee.name} Payment : ${employee.payment} Bonus: ${employee.bonus} @PrasadKhode, agad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you need to create the data objects that you want to display in your excel file

```
List<Staff> staffs = new ArrayList<Staff>();
staffs.add(new Staff("Zhang San", 6000D, 3000D));
staffs.add(new Staff("Li Si", 5000D, 2000D));
staffs.add(new Staff("Wang Wu", 4000D, 1000D));
```

then add the data into `java.util.Map`

```
Map<String, List<Staff>> beanParams = new HashMap<String, List<Staff>>();
beanParams.put("staffs", staffs);
```

then create `XLSTransformer` object and set the source file, destination file and the map which is holding your data

```
XLSTransformer former = new XLSTransformer();
former.transformXLS(srcFilePath, beanParams, destFilePath);
```

you need to use `<jx:forEach>` tag to iterate over the list which is in your map and then you can set the values into your result excel file. Change your excel template file with the following

[image]